# is possible to combine two raids groups in one logical drive

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

i have server with raid card support 8 disk drive and and created raid. but to to large data storage getting full. so i want to know if i add another raid card with same model and capacity. and create same raid like raid 10 or 5 on both raid drives. is possible i will merge both raid storage as one drive.
server
del T630
internal sotrage bay 8 with 8tbx8
external storage bay 8 with 8tbx8
and use same raid cards for both raids and same raid type like raid 5 or 10

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 22. and mysql 8.0. its actually a database server where one database size getting increased by 100gb every day.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use entirely software approach via LVM.

Let suppose you see from OS the hardware arrays as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. You do not have LVM configured. Have two partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` for `boot` and `/`.

1. create new partition in `/dev/sda`, for example `/dev/sda3`
2. create PV on this partition and second disk

   `pvcreate /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb`
3. Create VG

   `vgcreate bigvolume /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb`
4. create LV

   `lvcreate -L 20GB -n bigdata1 bigvolume`
5. create filesystem

   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/bigvolume-bigdata1`
6. Mount is somewhere:

   `mount /dev/mapper/bigvolume-bigdata1  /somewhere`

In above example type of filesystem and mountpoint are just examples

Comment: It's ok . But other question. Is it's harful for raid actual work or not. I mean of use lvm for murge two partions belongs to two different raid group.. will effect raid or not. Is raid will work as normal or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it's harful for raid actual work or not"? And if you have new question please use https://serverfault.com/questions/ask

Comment: I mean raid backup feature will if we use above method?

Comment: @OwaisMaqsood, do you tail about snapshots? And RAID is not a backup

Comment: No sir, I mean raid actual work. If we merge two raids and any drive from one raid got problem. And we replace bad drive. Then data will work or not?

Comment: @OwaisMaqsood, you do not merge RAIDs on hardware level. They continue to be independent. You represent then to the OS as one drive via kind of virtualisation. So if you repair one RAID and start computer the recovery of information on this drive will happen on controller level. And OS will continue to see the same volume